# Выполнение кода при завершении программы python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как выполнять код после завершения программы от имени пользователя?
к примеру:
os.remove(‘file.txt’)

Comment: "выполнять код после завершения программы"?

Comment: Может просто дописать эту строчку в самый конец программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `try/finally`. Даже если случилось исключение блок `finally` будет исполнен:

```
import time

try:
    while True:
        print('press Ctrl-C to stop')
        time.sleep(1)
finally:
    print('\n\nCleanup code is here\n')
```

> ```
> $ python cleanup.py 
> press Ctrl-C to stop
> press Ctrl-C to stop
> press Ctrl-C to stop
> ^C
>
> Cleanup code is here
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "cleanup.py", line 7, in <module>
>     time.sleep(1)
> KeyboardInterrupt
> ```

Можно обработать `KeyboardInterrupt` чтобы исключение не портило настроение в конце программы:

```
import time

try:
    while True:
        print('press Ctrl-C to stop')
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n\nKeyboardInterrupt cleanup code is here')
finally:
    print('\n\nCommon cleanup code is here')
```

> ```
> $ python cleanup.py 
> press Ctrl-C to stop
> press Ctrl-C to stop
> press Ctrl-C to stop
> ^C
>
> KeyboardInterrupt cleanup code is here
>
>
> Common cleanup code is here
> ```